# Simple Apache Rewrite Issue Passing Variables

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

For some reason I'm having an issue with a rewrite rule that I assume should be very easy.

I would like to rewrite site.com/page.html?1 to site.com/page.php?p=1
and site.com/page.html to site.com/page.php

here is what I assumed should work, but doesn't:

```
RewriteRule page.html?([^/\.]+)/?$ page.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query string (portion of URL after the ?) is not included in the regex portion of a `RewriteRule`. Just the requested page path/name. If you want to capture the query string you would need to use a `RewriteCond` and capture the `%{QUERY_STRING}` environment variable. Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\d*)
RewriteRule page.html page.php?p=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Notice, I now capture the query string in the `RewriteCond`, removed the trailing `?...` from the end of the regex in `RewriteRule` and also changed the variable in the replace with `%1` instead of `$1` to refer to the captured condition instead of rule. You can also change the regex in the condition to better match what you want.

Edit: Also, keep in mind that the QSA will append any query string not already present in the rewritten URL. So if you leave that in there, if you are passing a query string like `?1`, you will still get a key appended to the URL of `1` with an empty value (`?1` => `array(1=>'')`). If you don't need additional query string values, just remove QSA or if you want the extra values and don't care about blank query string parameters (doesn't hurt unless you are looping over all of $_GET), then leave it in there.

Comment: Then check and make sure that `p` is set **and** that `p` is NOT empty since this will always have the `$_GET['p']` as set. I personally used the following:
`if(isset($_GET['p']) && !empty($_GET['p']))`

Comment: @Kaboom you could also change the regex pattern in the condition to something like `(\d+)` to require at least one number or some other pattern that requires a value as necessary using anchors or similar. If the condition pattern fails, the RewriteRule is skipped meaning that if there are no rules to match, a 404 error would be generated (page doesn't exist as `*.html`) and an apache ErrorDocument could be loaded to handle that. I just made the pattern pretty broad so it would load the desired `*.php` page.

Comment: Thanks, this works great. The only issue I come into is when the variable is a string rather than numbers.

For example if i try to pass site.com/page.html?test it will not pass it. However, if i pass site.com/page.html?123 it has no proablem. 

Is there a way to allow both to function?

thanks

Comment: The pattern I'm using in the condition is `(\d+)`. That can essentially be any pattern like the other ones. So you could simply put `(.+)` to capture anything or a little more strict `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` to capture any single block of letters/numbers (no spaces, slashes, symbols, etc).

Answer (score -1):

If the value of `p` is always an integer, try:

```
RewriteRule page\.html\?([\d]+)$ page.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Tested on https://regex101.com/r/3AFu0A/1

Comment: While the regex does match a query string, the query string is not included for the regex to match for a `RewriteRule`. Just the requested URI name/path up to, but not including, the query string.